# How to find the path to the minimum?

Tags: python, recursion, depth-first-search

One day a castle is attacked at sunrise (by surprise) by n soldiers.

Each soldier carries a canon and a rifle.

The castle has strength s.

On the first day each soldier shoots his canon at the castle costing the castle n strength points (i.e. the castle ends the first day with s=s-n strength points). After all the soldiers have fired, the castle sends dpw defenders to battle them.

In the ensuing days the castle and the soldiers battle it out following these rules:

1. All the soldiers fire first. A soldier can fire his canon at the
   castle or his rifle at one of the defenders (but not both and each
   soldier can only shoot once). One shot at a defender kills him. One
   shot at the castle decreases its strength by 1.
2. Then each of the d defenders shoots at one soldier (and only one) killing him.
3. If the castle still has strength points (i.e. s>0) it sends a new batch of dpw defenders at this point. The total number of defenders in the next round will be d=d+dpw.
4. Repeat 1 through 3 on each new day.
5. If all soldiers are killed by the defenders, the castle wins.
6. If there are zero defenders after the soldiers shoot and the castle strength is zero, the soldiers win.

We would like to know the minimum number of rounds the soldiers need to win the game (or if not possible return -1).

We would also like to know the number of soldiers, defenders and castle strength at the beginning of each round for the minimum number of rounds solution.

To find the minimum number of rounds I wrote this python program (which works correctly)

```
global dpw

# called when the castleStrenght=0. At this point
# the game goes on with soldiers killing defenders and
# defenders killing soldiers but there are no new 
# defenders being added since the castle is gone  
def kill(soldiers,totalDefenders):
     if totalDefenders <= 0:
        return 0
     if soldiers <=0:
        return 999999999
     soldiersLeft = soldiers - (totalDefenders - soldiers)
     totalDefendersLeft = totalDefenders - soldiers
     return 1 + kill(soldiersLeft, totalDefendersLeft)

# simulates one round of the game
def round(soldiers, totalDefenders, castleHits):
       if soldiers <= 0:
            return 999999999
       if castleHits <= 0:            
            return kill(soldiers, totalDefenders - dpw)
       mini = 999999999
       for i in range(0,soldiers):
             if  (i > totalDefenders):
                 break
             soldiersLeft = soldiers - (totalDefenders - i)
             totalDefendersLeft = totalDefenders - i + dpw
             castleHitsLeft =  castleHits - (soldiers - i) 
             mini = min(mini, 1 + round(soldiersLeft, totalDefendersLeft, castleHitsLeft))
       return mini

# run the game
def attackCastle(soldiers,castleHits,defendersPerRound):
       global dpw
       dpw = defendersPerRound
       ret = round(soldiers,0,castleHits)
       if ret >= 99999999:
           return -1
       else:
           return ret


gameSoldiers = 10
castleStrength = 11
defendersPerWave = 15

#prints 4
print attackCastle(gameSoldiers, castleStrength, defendersPerWave)
```

I am stuck however on how to obtain the number of soldiers, castle strength and total defenders at the beginning of each round. I think I need to pass a stack like variable during the recursive calls, but I need to pop items when I backtrack. Not sure how to do it though? I started by modifying the code above like this

```
global dpw

def kill(soldiers,totalDefenders,path):
     if totalDefenders <= 0:
        return 0
     if soldiers <=0:
        return 999999999
     soldiersLeft = soldiers - (totalDefenders - soldiers)
     totalDefendersLeft = totalDefenders - soldiers
     path.append({"soldiers":soldiersLeft,"totalDefenders":totalDefendersLeft,
                           "castleHits":0})
     return 1 + kill(soldiersLeft, totalDefendersLeft,path)

def round(soldiers, totalDefenders, castleHits,path):
       if soldiers <= 0:
            return 999999999
       if castleHits <= 0:
            path.append({"soldiers":soldiers,"totalDefenders":totalDefenders-dpw,
                           "castleHits":0})
            return kill(soldiers, totalDefenders - dpw,path)
       mini = 999999999
       for i in range(0,soldiers):
             if  (i > totalDefenders):
                 break
             soldiersLeft = soldiers - (totalDefenders - i)
             totalDefendersLeft = totalDefenders - i + dpw
             castleHitsLeft =  castleHits - (soldiers - i) 
             path.append({"soldiers":soldiersLeft,"totalDefenders":totalDefendersLeft,
                           "castleHits":castleHitsLeft})
             mini = min(mini, 1 + round(soldiersLeft, totalDefendersLeft, castleHitsLeft,path))

       return mini

def attackCastle(soldiers,castleHits,defendersPerRound):
       global dpw
       dpw = defendersPerRound
       ret = round(soldiers,0,castleHits,[])
       if ret >= 99999999:
           return -1
       else:
           return ret

gameSoldiers = 10
castleStrength = 11
defendersPerWave = 15

#prints 4
print attackCastle(gameSoldiers, castleStrength, defendersPerWave)
```

Comment: Can you comment your code? It's mostly self explanatory with the useful variable names. But what do the functions do?

Comment: what does dpw stand for?

Comment: @Anachor I added comments to the functions in the first code (the second is similar other then I tentatively added the path as a variable to track the quantities)

Comment: @SirParselot dpw=defenders per wave or per round. The number of defenders the castle sends at the end of each day (if castleStrength>0). It is always the same number every day.

Comment: When I see this many globals it usually means you need a class, also round is a builtin function.